# Nlog -Mongodb create collection

Tags: mongodb, asp.net-core, nlog

I'm using Nlog(4.7.5), Nlog.mongo(4.6.0.118) and mongoDB.Driver(2.11.3).
when logging with mongodb I need to create collection like this **`"log-2020-10-18"`**.
so the 18th date logs are store in this  collection. The next day or etc. logs will store in **`"log-${shortdate}"`** collection. everyday the logs store in the format of collection name.
in short I want to store logs daywise in mongodb.so it will easy to see day to day logs.
can I create collection at runtime(I mean in nlog.config file)
so is that possible to do that? how?

here is the mongodb target

```
    <target xsi:type="Database"
                    name="mongo"
                    includeDefaults="false"
                    connectionString="mongodb://localhost/financeLogs"
                    collectionName="log-${shortdate}"
                    databaseName="financeLogs">
                <property name="LongDate" layout="${longdate}" bsonType="DateTime" />
                <property name="Level" layout="${level}"/>
                <property name="Message" layout="${message}"/>
    
            </target>
```

InternalLogger logs

```
2020-10-18 14:26:06.1806 Warn Error when setting 'log-${shortdate}' on attibute 'collectionName' Exception: System.NotSupportedException: Parameter collectionName not supported on DatabaseTarget
   at NLog.Internal.PropertyHelper.SetPropertyFromString(Object obj, String propertyName, String value, ConfigurationItemFactory configurationItemFactory)
   at NLog.Config.LoggingConfigurationParser.ConfigureObjectFromAttributes(Object targetObject, ILoggingConfigurationElement element, Boolean ignoreType)
2020-10-18 14:26:06.2640 Error Exception when parsing D:\Git\finance.api\FinanceAPI\bin\Debug\netcoreapp3.1\nlog.Development.config.  Exception: System.NotSupportedException: Parameter collectionName not supported on DatabaseTarget
   at NLog.Internal.PropertyHelper.SetPropertyFromString(Object obj, String propertyName, String value, ConfigurationItemFactory configurationItemFactory)
   at NLog.Config.LoggingConfigurationParser.ConfigureObjectFromAttributes(Object targetObject, ILoggingConfigurationElement element, Boolean ignoreType)
   at NLog.Config.LoggingConfigurationParser.ParseTargetElement(Target target, ILoggingConfigurationElement targetElement, Dictionary`2 typeNameToDefaultTargetParameters)
   at NLog.Config.LoggingConfigurationParser.ParseTargetsElement(ILoggingConfigurationElement targetsElement)
   at NLog.Config.LoggingConfigurationParser.ParseNLogSection(ILoggingConfigurationElement configSection)
   at NLog.Config.XmlLoggingConfiguration.ParseNLogSection(ILoggingConfigurationElement configSection)
   at NLog.Config.LoggingConfigurationParser.LoadConfig(ILoggingConfigurationElement nlogConfig, String basePath)
   at NLog.Config.XmlLoggingConfiguration.ParseNLogElement(ILoggingConfigurationElement nlogElement, String filePath, Boolean autoReloadDefault)
   at NLog.Config.XmlLoggingConfiguration.ParseTopLevel(NLogXmlElement content, String filePath, Boolean autoReloadDefault)
   at NLog.Config.XmlLoggingConfiguration.Initialize(XmlReader reader, String fileName, Boolean ignoreErrors)
2020-10-18 14:26:06.2980 Warn Error has been raised. Exception: NLog.NLogConfigurationException: Exception when parsing D:\Git\finance.api\FinanceAPI\bin\Debug\netcoreapp3.1\nlog.Development.config. 
 ---> System.NotSupportedException: Parameter collectionName not supported on DatabaseTarget
   at NLog.Internal.PropertyHelper.SetPropertyFromString(Object obj, String propertyName, String value, ConfigurationItemFactory configurationItemFactory)
   at NLog.Config.LoggingConfigurationParser.ConfigureObjectFromAttributes(Object targetObject, ILoggingConfigurationElement element, Boolean ignoreType)
   at NLog.Config.LoggingConfigurationParser.ParseTargetElement(Target target, ILoggingConfigurationElement targetElement, Dictionary`2 typeNameToDefaultTargetParameters)
   at NLog.Config.LoggingConfigurationParser.ParseTargetsElement(ILoggingConfigurationElement targetsElement)
   at NLog.Config.LoggingConfigurationParser.ParseNLogSection(ILoggingConfigurationElement configSection)
   at NLog.Config.XmlLoggingConfiguration.ParseNLogSection(ILoggingConfigurationElement configSection)
   at NLog.Config.LoggingConfigurationParser.LoadConfig(ILoggingConfigurationElement nlogConfig, String basePath)
   at NLog.Config.XmlLoggingConfiguration.ParseNLogElement(ILoggingConfigurationElement nlogElement, String filePath, Boolean autoReloadDefault)
   at NLog.Config.XmlLoggingConfiguration.ParseTopLevel(NLogXmlElement content, String filePath, Boolean autoReloadDefault)
   at NLog.Config.XmlLoggingConfiguration.Initialize(XmlReader reader, String fileName, Boolean ignoreErrors)
   --- End of inner exception stack trace ---
2020-10-18 14:26:06.3558 Info Validating config: TargetNames=file, fileAsException, ConfigItems=56, FilePath=D:\Git\finance.api\FinanceAPI\bin\Debug\netcoreapp3.1\nlog.Development.config
2020-10-18 14:26:06.3859 Warn Unused target detected. Add a rule for this target to the configuration. TargetName: file
2020-10-18 14:26:06.3975 Warn Unused target detected. Add a rule for this target to the configuration. TargetName: fileAsException
```

Comment: Remember also to use `xsi:type="Mongo"` and not `xsi:type="Database"`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have you tried this (Notice the use of `xsi:type="Mongo"`):

```xml
    <target xsi:type="Mongo"
            name="mongo"
            includeDefaults="false"
            connectionString="mongodb://localhost/financeLogs"
            collectionName="log-${shortdate}"
            databaseName="financeLogs">
        <property name="LongDate" layout="${longdate}" bsonType="DateTime" />
        <property name="Level" layout="${level}"/>
        <property name="Message" layout="${message}"/>
    </target>
```

Make sure to use https://www.nuget.org/packages/NLog.Mongo/4.6.0.123 (or newer) for improved support of using `${shortdate}` in `collectionName=`

Comment: @BhavinVarsur "Not work" is very vague. Is the first collection created? Does it fail to create the next collection on day-roll ? Could you enable the NLog InternalLogger and show the output on initial creation and on day rolls? See also: https://github.com/NLog/NLog/wiki/Internal-Logging

Comment: Ah. I see the problem now: https://github.com/loresoft/NLog.Mongo/blob/b0788a8db0efcea2442f0d2925530f54e7ecc528/src/NLog.Mongo/MongoTarget.cs#L398 (`_defaultLogEvent` is not a good value for rolling date)

Comment: i just added target from [https://github.com/loresoft/NLog.Mongo/issues/25].[1] and collection name which is in your answer. i amaze it's work now. Thank you !!

Comment: @BhavinVarsur Created pull-request to improve support for datetime-layout-renderers: https://github.com/loresoft/NLog.Mongo/pull/53

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/223250/discussion-between-bhavin-varsur-and-rolf-kristensen).

Comment: @BhavinVarsur https://www.nuget.org/packages/NLog.Mongo/4.6.0.123 has now been released with support for ${shortdate} in collection-name.